# .htaccess problem in angular7 application and wordpress application

Tags: angular, wordpress, .htaccess

I have both an angular7 application and Wordpress application. Angular7 application runs in the root folder. Wordpress runs in "blog"(Subfolder). I have added "blog" as a static folder in angular.json. My angular application was running successfully. But my Wordpress was not running.

Here I attached the .htaccess file for both. Please help me to resolve this

Angular Build: https://example.com
Wordpress: https://example.com/blog

.htaccess for Angular application

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]    
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess for wordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem. If I understand correctly the structure of your folders is as follows:

```
|– www/           // your root directory
|   |– blog/      // your blog sub-directory
```

When you are in the blog subdirectory you have to treat it as if it were the current directory inside the `.htaccess`.
The rules with `/blog/` are wrong, for example:

```
RewriteRule. /blog/index.php [L]
```

You could try in:

```
www/blog/.htaccess
```

This `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: I have deleted everything and installed the wordpress again with your .htaccess suggestion. It works. Thanks